# Running MVC6 app on IIS10 throws 500 error

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to deploy a MVC 6 to IIS. I have followed these instructions http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html but the app will not run. It throws a 500 error. I then tried the stock standard template MVC 6 app deployed to IIS and that would not run either. No 500 thrown. Just a blank page. In both cases the apps run correctly in IIS express. In both cases I used the File Publish method from VS pointing to the wwwroot folder.

In IIS config editor, I have unlocked the handlers. In the wwwroot web.config I have set CustomerErrors mode to Off.

The DNX version I am using in the File System deployment is dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final.

Comment: Have a look in the Windows event logs to see if there is a more detailed error message available. (You may be better off developing with IIS rather than IIS Express on your development machine, and keep a note of all the configuration changes you have to make to get it to work, e.g. setting SQL Server logins and permissions.)

Comment: I have checked Event Logs, IIS Logs and even tried to hook up the dnx logs.

Comment: In the IIS log, there should be a sub-code for the 500 error, which might help. [The HTTP status code in IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/943891).

Comment: Ok- well this is IIS10 - nothing in the logs : #Date: 2016-01-20 20:29:37
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2016-01-20 20:29:37 ::1 GET /MyApartment - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/47.0.2526.111+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 7
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-01-20 20:30:50

Comment: In the publish folder "wwwroot" has web.config, in that set "stdoutLogEnabled" to TRUE. After this run application, in "logs" folder. You will get some details. Look for those details.

Comment: So you have "500.0 - Module or ISAPI error occurred." Which narrows it down a *little* bit. I suggest you get it working in IIS on a Windows 10 development machine and see if you need to add anything to IIS through Control Panel->Programs and Features->Turn Windows features on and off->Internet Information Services.

Comment: @Mithun - Yes, I have that setting in the config file.No logs are produced

Comment: @Andrew - I have tried all the combinations - removed IIS and then enabled it again. This is on my development machine. There simply is not enough information to establish a cause.